# betareg not using multithreading on CentOS

Tags: r, conda, blas, rparallel, betareg

### Model Fitting Runs Single-Threaded on CentOS

I am fitting a mixture of Beta regressions model with the `betamix` function from [the **betareg** package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/index.html). I originally developed the code on Mac OS X, but am now running it (i.e., moving to *at scale*) on an HPC cluster with LSF for job management and CentOS on the nodes. For both situations I use Conda environments defined by the following YAML

**betareg.yaml**

```yaml
name: betareg
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - r-base=4.0.3
  - r-tidyverse
  - r-magrittr
  - r-cowplot
  - r-knitr  
  - r-flexmix
  - r-betareg
```

On my local machine, the `betamix` step automatically scales to all available cores. On the cluster, however, where I deploy jobs via Snakemake and provided `threads: 16`, monitoring shows all jobs are running single-threaded despite the Snakemake logs clearly showing correct allocation of 16 cores per job.

#### Parallel Package?

Comparing `sessionInfo()` output for both situations showed a lack of `parallel` being loaded on HPC context. However, explicitly adding `library(parallel)` did not make a difference.

#### Identical BLAS Library Versions

Another thought was that perhaps the BLAS libraries were different, however, these also appear to match (though obviously platform-specific builds).

**osx-64 BLAS**

```r
## Matrix products: default
## BLAS/LAPACK: /Users/user/miniconda3/envs/betareg/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.12.dylib
```

**linux-64 BLAS**

```r
## Matrix products: default
## BLAS/LAPACK: /home/user/mm-stem-cluster/.snakemake/conda/80842b70/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.12.so
```

**How can I get the CentOS execution to use all allocated threads?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Specify Threads with RhpcBLASctl

[The RhpcBLASctl package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RhpcBLASctl/index.html) provides a method `blas_set_num_threads()` that appears sufficient to enable use of the specified number of threads. For this specific application, I updated the YAML to

**betareg.yaml**

```yaml
name: betareg
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - r-base=4.0.3
  - r-tidyverse
  - r-magrittr
  - r-cowplot
  - r-knitr  
  - r-flexmix
  - r-betareg
  - r-rhpcblasctl
```

and added the following to set correct number of threads in the script:

```r
RhpcBLASctl::blas_set_num_threads(snakemake@threads)
```